# onTouchEvent in OpenGLRenderer?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I created a OpenGL Renderer

```
public class OpenGLRenderer implements Renderer {
```

And now I want to get data from onTouchEvent.
Unfortunately, it doesn't work:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    //eyeX += 0.2f;
    //eyeY = 0.2f;
    eyeZ -= 0.2f;
    Log.v("OpenGLRenderer", "TouchEvent works");
    return true;
}
```

When I change my class to:

```
public class OpenGLRenderer extends GLSurfaceView implements Renderer {
```

and my onTouchEvent function to:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    //eyeX += 0.2f;
    //eyeY = 0.2f;
    eyeZ -= 0.2f;
    Log.v("OpenGLRenderer", "TouchEvent works");
    return true;
}
```

still not works :/
What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

From the GLSurfaceView [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html): "When handling the event, you may need to communicate with the Renderer object that's running in the rendering thread."

Use `queueEvent(Runnable)` to pass the event to the rendering Thread:

```
@override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
queueEvent(new Runnable() {
                 // This method will be called on the rendering
                 // thread:
                 public void run() {
                     eyeZ -= 0.2f;
    Log.v("OpenGLRenderer", "TouchEvent works");
                 }});
return true;
}
```

Comment: I did my class implement OnTouchListener and Eclipse created for me public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { , but it don't work. I don't know what I should do in constructor (you wrote that I should write setonTouchListener(this); but Eclipse don't know what's this :P)

Answer (score 0):

This is for MyGLSurfaceview class..
    when you touch the screen, you will get the that position x,y position range.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    // Normal touch
    xPosition = ev.getX();
    yPosition = ev.getY();

    switch (ev.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
            dx = ev.getX();
            dy = ev.getY();
        }

        return ;
    }
}
```